# passing gallery image to another activity through intent

Tags: android

I need to send a image from gallery to another activity by using the path of that image but nothing happened...
help me out......
here is the code..

```
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
           if(requestCode==RESULT_LOADIMAGE&&resultCode==RESULT_OK&&null!=data)
       {
        Uri selectedImages=data.getData();
        String[] filePathColon={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursr=getContentResolver().query(selectedImages, filePathColon, null, null, null);
        cursr.moveToFirst();
        int columnindex=cursr.getColumnIndex(filePathColon[0]);
        String picturepath=cursr.getString(columnindex);
        cursr.close();

    Intent  intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("imagePath",filePathColon );
        startActivity(intent);

       }
   }
```

and second activity code is

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


       getData();

       }

      private void getData(){
    String ps=getIntent().getStringExtra("imagepath");

    img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ps));

}
```

Comment: please mark a useful answer

Answer (score 2):

```
intent.putExtra("imagePath",filePathColon );
```

should be

```
intent.putExtra("imagePath",picturepath);
```

**because filepathcolon refers to column index and picturepath refers to the URI**

and get it using

```
String ps=getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath"); //it should be same as you send it
```

Answer (score 2):

please change like this

```
      Intent  intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("imagePath",picturepath);
    startActivity(intent);

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The two strings in your Intent do not match:
You wrote imagePath with capital P in the first Activity, but not in your second one.

```
String ps=getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
```

fixes it